# Mapbox with only United States

Tags: json, maps, mapbox, geojson

I'm developing a map using mapbox and I am trying to "remove/hide" all countries except the United States.

I already have the map centered and bounded to the US but I feel like the whole map would look cleaner if the other countries were simply hidden. I don't have a lot of experience with mapbox or its coding language so I don't know if this is possible or if I just don't know how to do it. I've looked all over and I can't seem to find a way to do this using mapbox studio.

This is my mapid coltonneil.3dc5d18e. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This article from the Mapbox documentation walks through the steps to create a map for just one country or area: https://www.mapbox.com/help/style-single-country/